# Vuex is not mutating the state

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to switch `authenticated` from `false` to `true`, a property in the `state`, It's not working.

My codes from store.js

```
state() {
    return{
       authenticated : false,
       user : {}
    }
},

getters : {
    authenticated(state){
        return state.authenticated
    }
},

mutations : {
    set_authenticated(state, value){
        return state.authenticated = value
    }
},
```

My updated code from login.vue (script)

```
data() {
    return {
       allerrors : [],
       success : false,
       data: {
           email : "",
           password : ""
       }
    }
},

methods : {
    login: function() {
    this.$store
        .dispatch("login", this.data)
        .then(response => {
                            this.allerrors = [],
                            this.success = true,
                            this.data = {}
                            alert(response.data)
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            this.allerrors = error.response.data.error
                            this.success = false
                            alert(allerrors)
                        })
    },
```

My updated action is :

```
 async login({ commit }, data) {
        await axios.post('login', data)
         .then(response => {
           commit('set_authenticated',true);
           })
         .catch((error) => {
           this.allerrors = error.response.data.error
           this.success = false
          })
    }
```

Comment: state is an function that returns an object. In your case, is just a object

Comment: I am new in vuejs that's why messing lol, would you please tell me how can I resolve it

Comment: You can see it at the first page "Getting started" how it should look like https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store

Comment: still the problem exists

Comment: `authenticated(state){
        return state.authenticated
    }` - this doesn't serve a good purpose. Otherwise the code you posted doesn't contain the problem you describe. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: should I remove getters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

First, if that is the full code for your `store.js` file, then you are missing the call to `createStore()` (for Vue 3) or `new Vuex.Store()` (for Vue 2)

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

// Create a new store instance.
const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
})
```

[Source](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store)

The second problem is that you shouldn't be committing mutations from your Single File Components. The typical flow is:

- Components dispatch actions
- Actions commit mutations
- Mutations update state

You're trying to commit a mutation directly from the component.

You need to add an action to your `store.js`

```js
async login({ commit }, userData) {
  await axios.post('login', userData)
   .then(response => {
     commit('set_authenticated',true);
     })
   .catch((error) => {
     this.allerrors = error.response.data.error
     this.success = false
    })
   }
```

Mutation:

```js
mutations : {
    set_authenticated(state, value){
        state.authenticated = value
    }
},
```

Then your `Login.vue` would change to something like:

```js
  methods: {
    login: function() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch("login", { userData })
        .then(() => )) // whatever you want to do here.
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
  }
```

Comment: where does the `userData` come from?

Comment: I used that as a placeholder. `userData` will be whatever values that you're trying to submit with the login. Email, password, username, etc.

Comment: it says cannot read property of undefined for `userData` in action

Comment: `userData` in my sample code is taking the place of `this.data` in your code. Because in your `Login.vue` component, you're not going to make the Axios call there. You're going to pass whatever data you were going to use with the Axios call as `userData` and it will be used in the action, when the action makes the Axios call.

Comment: brother, please check my updated question. I have added my action and script from template. I guess I made mistake while passing `data` from template to action

Comment: Can you replace `this.data` in your dispatch with `{email: this.email, password: this.password}`?

Comment: You need to provide additional information about the exact errors you are seeing in order to troubleshoot.

Comment: I am not getting any error now, but it sets `authenticated` true initially ( while submitting the form ), but while reloading the page, it shows false again

Comment: If you're not doing anything to persist the state, then it will reset on page load.

Comment: would you tell me how can I persist state

Comment: so vuex does not store data, like session / cookie does ?

Comment: When you use your actions you can also set the item in localStorage/sessionStorage before committing the mutation.

Comment: Ok I got it bro, thanks for your time and kind help

Comment: please tell me another thing, so vuex store is not reliable for authentication system and I should use laravel sanctum or some other storage system (cookie/session) for that, right ?

Comment: I mean ideally you're going to want some sort of cookie/session system in place. I don't have any knowledge of Laravel Sanctum but if that's a fit for your stack then pursue it. Alternatively, `vuex-persistedstate` is an NPM package that's available, but deprecated. It will allow you to persist state through page refresh. But you'll eventually have to roll your own solution since it's no longer actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

mutations shouldn't have a return statement. it should be like this

```
mutations : {
    set_authenticated(state, value){
        state.authenticated = value
    }
},
```

Comment: still not working brother

Comment: are you using modules or a single store file ?

Comment: single store file